# How can i run 'while' statement every x seconds

Tags: c#, timer, while-loop, wait

I'm  checking if a process is running and if not start that process. 
It works fine, but only once, after that, the statement is finished and doesn't run again, which is expected.

but I can't figure out how to run it every X seconds.

this is the code I have:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (checkBox1.Checked)
        {

            var retVal = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName.Contains(textBox1.Text));

            if (retVal.Equals(true))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + @" " + @"is running." + @" " + DateTime.Now);
                return;
            }

             if (retVal.Equals(false))
             {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + @" " + @"is not running, attempting to start." + DateTime.Now);
                    Process.Start(textBox2.Text);
                    return;
             }
        }
    }
```

Now I know the return statement at the end of each if statement will stop the code, but if I don't have that it will crash the app because it will just write continually to the list box.

How can I run the code

```
while (checkBox1.Checked)
```

every X seconds?

Comment: Use `Thread.Sleep` or better use the `System.Timers` class

Answer (score 1):

You can use timer to check it. It is really simple.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!checkBox1.Checked) return;
        var retVal = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName.Contains(textBox1.Text));
        if (retVal.Equals(true))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + @" " + @"is running." + @" " + DateTime.Now);
            return;
        }

        if (!retVal.Equals(false)) return;
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + @" " + @"is not running, attempting to start." + DateTime.Now);
        Process.Start(textBox2.Text);
    }
```

And you can choose your interval from properties of timer. Remember it is miliseconds (1000ms = 1 second).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably use WinForms, your code looks very much like that, but as it isn't in your question, I'll add another solutin to OmerCDs.

You could use `Task.Delay`. However, this hibernates the thread, therefore it shouldn't be run on the main thread. You could use a code like this:

```
    Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                var retVal = Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProcessName.Contains(textBox1.Text));
                if (retVal.Equals(true))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + @" " + @"is running." + @" " + DateTime.Now);
                    return;
                }
                if (retVal.Equals(false))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(
                        textBox1.Text + @" " + @"is not running, attempting to start." + DateTime.Now);
                    Process.Start(textBox2.Text);
                    return;
                }
            }
            await Task.Delay(2 /*your waiting time in seconds*/ * 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not just use Task.Delay instead of an embedded Thread.Sleep?